# Unlink Windows login from database user in SQL Server contained database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, logins, contained-database

I'm migrating databases from SQL Server 2012 to Server Server 2017, and switching SOME of them to partially contained.  I've done SQL Server backups and restores to actually move the databases, and switched them to partially contained.  When I then recreate the Windows-based logins at the server/instance level, they are automagically reconnected to the database users - in both the partially contained and non-contained databases.  For the users in the partially contained databases, I would like to break the link between the instance-level Windows login and database user, so that the authentication happens at the database level (but it's still a Windows login). I don't want to drop the instance-level Windows login because it is needed for other databases.

`sp_migrate_user_to_contained` is only for SQL Server logins, not Windows-based logins.  I could try one of the scripts out there for cloning a user and basically drop the existing user and recreate it, but I'm hoping not to.

Is what I'm trying to do not really supported, or maybe just pointless?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. But why do you want to?

Comment: I thought doing this was part of making the database as contained as possible.  But I'm beginning to think it doesn't make any difference.